# Postfix/Dovecot Mail server with multiple domains and SSL

Tags: centos, ssl, postfix, email-server, dovecot

On my mail setup I'm currently using self signed certificate generated for server hostname.

And I'm curious is there some kind of SSL certificate that shared hosting providers use for multiple domains mail and how are they setting them up?

Comment: They might use wildcard SSL certificates, for e.g. *.example.net

Comment: I can't use it because it covers only all subdomains of one domain and I have multiple domains.

Comment: You can use wildcard certificate for each of domain

Comment: I considered that too, but that would mean that I would need to rise price for my customers a lot as those certs are not cheap and price of work needed to to buy implement new cert on mail server. 

I was hoping there was some more elegant solution for this.

Comment: How your customers use certificates? May be single  master relay with single certificate is enough?

Comment: They currently are using mail over their own domains, example: mail.customer-domain1.com, mail.customer-domain2.com, mail.customer-domain3.com... So moving them to the one master relay this late in process is not so good option (it's doable but I don't like it).

Comment: Can I maybe buy cert for one domain (server hostname) and then via DNS MX records redirect mail.customer-domain-*.com to that domain? Will that work or will it say that ssl is not for that domain?

Are there SSL certs that can't be tied to a server(IP) instead of domain name?

Answer (score 2):

If you want each domain to use a valid SSL certificate, you have 2 solutions:
use a multi-domain certificate, or set up each domain on a unique IP.
The first solution is terrible: those certificates are usually quite expensive (though you can find inexpensive ones), they will list all of the domains you wish to certify on the same cert, and, most importantly, they are only issued once, so adding just one new domain means getting an entirely new cert.

The better solution is to place each domain on its own IP, and then to match each certificate to its respective IP.

Here's how you do it in postfix.

You will first place your certificates for each domain in the **/etc/postfix/** directory (you can also create a **/etc/postfix/ssl/** directory)
Note: i use Plesk, which uses .pem certificate files, but you can also use .key and .cer files (.pem files are just a concat of .key and .cer file, in that order)

then, you need to modify the **master.cf** file in **/etc/postfix/**

originally, mine looked like this (probably because i added the last 3 IPs after i set up the server:

```
1.1.1.1- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=1.1.1.1 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

2.2.2.2- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=2.2.2.2 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

smtp inet n - n - - smtpd
smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticate d,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=

3.3.3.3- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=3.3.3.3 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

4.4.4.4- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=4.4.4.4 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

5.5.5.5- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=5.5.5.5 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4
```

Now, to bind each certificate to its corresponding IP, you do as follows:

```
1.1.1.1- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=1.1.1.1 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

2.2.2.2- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=2.2.2.2 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

3.3.3.3- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=3.3.3.3 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

4.4.4.4- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=4.4.4.4 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

5.5.5.5- unix - n n - - smtp -o smtp_bind_address=5.5.5.5 -o smtp_bind_address6= -o smtp_address_preference=ipv4

#smtp inet n - n - - smtpd
#smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=

1.1.1.1:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert1.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert1.pem
1.1.1.1:smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert1.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert1.pem
1.1.1.1:submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert1.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert1.pem

2.2.2.2:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert2.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert2.pem
2.2.2.2:smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert2.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert2.pem
2.2.2.2:submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert2.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert2.pem

3.3.3.3:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert3.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert3.pem
3.3.3.3:smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert3.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert3.pem
3.3.3.3:submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert3.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert3.pem

4.4.4.4:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert4.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert4.pem
4.4.4.4:smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert4.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert4.pem
4.4.4.4:submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert4.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert4.pem

5.5.5.5:smtp inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert5.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert5.pem
5.5.5.5:smtps inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert5.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert5.pem
5.5.5.5:submission inet n - n - - smtpd -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject -o smtpd_sender_restrictions= -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/postfix/cert5.pem -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/postfix/cert5.pem
```

That's it!! (don't forget to comment out the original lines as seen above)

PS: to do the same for POP/IMAP if you use courier-imap, you simply place copies of those .pem files in **/usr/share/courier-imap/** (or in the case of Plesk, you place them in **/usr/share/** )
and you name them as follows:
imapd.pem.xx.xx.xx.xx
pop3d.pem.xx.xx.xx.xx

where xx.xx.xx.xx is the respective IP address (the 2 certificates are copies of the same file)

Hope this helps!